# Python Boto get_report class call?

Tags: python, boto

What I am trying to do is get a report using Boto and Get_Report(). I have a valid report id, and seem to be having problems getting the python call correct. The call requires the variable ReportId and I have been trying various methods of getting it to accept the id.

```
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
MarketPlaceID = 'a'
Merchant = 'a'
AccessKeyID = 'a'
SecretKey = 'a'

program_name = sys.argv[0]
MarketPlaceID = sys.argv[1]
Merchant = sys.argv[2]
AccessKeyID = sys.argv[3]
SecretKey = sys.argv[4]

print 'MarketplaceID is ', MarketPlaceID
print 'Merchant is ', Merchant
print 'AccessKey is ', AccessKeyID
print 'Secret key is ', SecretKey
conn = MWSConnection(AccessKeyID,SecretKey)

conn.SellerId = Merchant
conn.Merchant = Merchant
conn.MarketplaceId = MarketPlaceID


myId = '1432456045'

# sample one
conn.get_report(ReportId=myId)

# sample two
conn.get_report(myId)

# sample three
conn.get_report(myId,)

# sample four
conn.get_report(1432456045)

# sample five
conn.get_report('1432456045')



if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv1:)
```

With each of these five variations, I get the same key error: KeyError: 'GetReport requires R+e+p+o+r+t+I+d argument(s)'. This example will take the four arguments (MarketPlaceID, Merchant, AccessKeyID, and SecretKey) and tries to call get_report. The id number is a valid report, I have successfully used the scratchpad and downloaded the csv file.

The object is to call the get_report() call with a value of an inventory file. The call within boto takes an argument of an integer. I have tried various versions from an integer, integer encased within a string, and a list of one integer. Each of these failed with the same access key error.

I know that the five samples that I have above don't work as I have them.  Has anyone successfully got the Get_report call to work?  And could you point me to what I am doing incorrect?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  The problem is actually in connection.py.

```
@requires('ReportId')
```

Should read

```
@requires(['ReportId'])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It turns out that this error was fixed in October 2012.  For some reason it's still showing up in my v2.6.  It looks like I'll have to reinstall boto.

Answer (score 0):

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/mws.html#boto.mws.connection.MWSConnection.get_report

### get_report() worked for me when I used something similar to this:

```
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection

MarketPlaceID = 'a'
MerchantID = 'a'
AccessKeyID = 'a'
SecretKey = 'a'

mws = MWSConnection(AccessKeyID,SecretKey)

mws.SellerId = MerchantID
mws.Merchant = MerchantID
mws.MarketplaceId = MarketPlaceID

report = mws.get_report(ReportId='1234567890')
```